# How to run a calculation if text is found

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to perform a division only if a text is found on a cell. ie: divide A1/B1 if column C contains the text "ml".
Can you please help? Seems basic but nothing that I have tried is working.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*ml*",E3:E222)),(E3/L3),"0")
```

Comment: You are testing the same cells as the one you want to divide.  You cannot do math on a cell that is text.  If the `ml` is there because of custom number formatting, then it does not exist and cannot be found using `SEARCH`

Answer (score 0):

Your sample formula does not match up with the description you give, I will assume the latter is what you want.

Try:

```
=IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("ml",C1)>0,A1/B1,""),"")
```

This will search for the string "ml" and if found, return `A1` divided by `B1`. It will return nothing if the string is not found or `B1 = 0` (since you can't divide by zero)

Comment: Or you can simply use `IFFERROR((SEARCH("ml",C1)>0)*A1/B1,"")`

Comment: Iferror() only has one F in it... but, as usual Scott's version is succinct.

Comment: Indeed it is, one of the joys of seeing of his solutions is their elegance (at least compared to mine). I keep hoping some of it will rub off

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad you and me both, slow going in my case :)